# Java GUI basic login with MySQL reporting wrong login information

Tags: java, mysql

I've got a GUI that has a MySQL jdbc which checks to make sure the user has inputted the correct login information, but for some reason, even if the information is listed in my database it's saying it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You have already extracted the values from the resultset in below code:

```
if (rs!=null && rs.next()) {
    orgUname = rs.getString("username");
    orPass = rs.getString("password");
}
```

Replace the below line as follows:

```
if (rs.next() && password.equals(rs.getString("password")) && username.equals(rs.getString("username"))) {
```

to

```
if (password.equals(orPass) && username.equals(orgUname)) {
```